# Application of Rouché's theorem outside the unit circle; Confusion about argument principle

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

I am preparing for my function theory exam and came across this problem.

Let $f(z) := z^8 - 8z^5+2$.

I want to count the number of roots in B:= $\big\{z \ \big| \left| z-2 \right| < \frac{1}{2} \big\}$. From plotting $f$ I know it has one root in $B$.

Using that for $z \in B$ we have $\frac{3}{2} < |z| < \frac{5}{2}$, and trying out several candidates for $g$, I sought upper and lower bounds such that one of the following equations is satisfied on $\partial B$:

If $|f|<|g|$ on $\partial B$, then  $\#_{roots} \ (f, B) = \#_{roots} (f+ g, B)$, and

if $|f-g| < |f| + |g|$ on $\partial B$, then  $\#_{roots} \ (f, B) = \#_{roots} (g, B)$, while in class we also used

if $|f+g| < |g|$ on $\partial B$, then  $\#_{roots} \ (f, B) = \#_{roots} (g, B)$.

Taking a closer look, $g$ has to have one complex root within $B$. I can't even think of a candidate right now.

I don't see a clear path to the solution of my problem.

I believe I have a hard time understanding the argument principle, due to it's various equivalent forms. Practically, do I chose one of its inequalities and stick to it or is it better to chose it depending on the problem I am trying to solve?

I know there are $5$ roots within the unit circle. And I know I can find 3 more roots in $B_2(0)$.

Comment: You have already posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919368/rouch%c3%a9-for-non-centered-circle). Then you deleted it. Now, instead of undeleting it, you are posting it again. Why?

Comment: I deleted the question earlier because I felt like I had not specified it enough and also I again tried solving it on my own. Now, after several further attempts, I decided to document what I have tried, well-define the problem more, and post it again. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I am fairly new to this community. Shall I rather undelete and rewrite the entire question in the future, if it is about the same problem?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That's the *second* time the OP does that, see [this other deleted copy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919399/rouch%C3%A9-for-non-centered-circle), too.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you. I had no idea.

Comment: It would be great if one could let me know how I could do it better next time.

Comment: @Clip Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/). I appreciate that you added some context this time around, but there was no reason to delete your same question (twice) and post new ones. Instead, edit the original question until it covers the ground. Besides, deleting and reposting is frowned upon, and will eventually attract (unwanted) moderator attention.

Comment: @dxiv thanks for clarification. I referenced another SE post that said deleting a question is fine as long as there are not any constructive answers yet.

Comment: @Clip: Editing, amending, and adding to your original question are all a good thing. Now, *totally changing* the question to a different question after people have helped you or answered you is not so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(z)=(z^3-8)(z^5-\frac14)=z^8-8z^5-\frac14z^3+2$. Then for $|z-2|=\frac12$, which implies $\frac32\le |z|\le\frac52$,
$$
|f(z)-g(z)|=\frac14|z|^3\le \frac{5^3}{2^5}\le 4
$$
and
$$
|g(z)|=|z-2|\cdot|z^2+2z+4|⋅|z^5-\tfrac14|\ge\frac12⋅(12-|z-2|⋅|z+4|)⋅((\tfrac32)^5-\tfrac14)\ge\frac12⋅8⋅7=28
$$
As these estimates establish $|g(z)|>|g(z)-f(z)|$ for $|z-2|=\frac12$, the polynomials $f$ and $g$ have the same number of roots in the disk $|z-2|<\frac12$ by Rouché's theorem. $g(z)$ has exactly one root, $z=2$, inside that disk.